# redirect user to a particular page in web view

Tags: android

I am creating a app in android that scans barcode and retrieves the information from my database.It works fine but now i want to integrate it with flipkart database.Or  redirect them to flipkart page of that product.But how do i access the flipkart database.
Say i scanned a book of android , now i would want to redirect my user to specific page on flipkart.Any help would be appreciated...thanks

Comment: Ask flipkart if they provide an API for doing such things. Otherwise your pretty much screwed without access to the data.

Comment: I have heard about web crawlers .Will it be of use in this context? I basically have to fetch rate of a book  from flipkart when the book is scanned though flipkart allows to search the product details by entering the books name not barcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to ask flipkart if they have a way to easily do this, and more importantly if its within their terms & conditions (so you don't break any laws).

Looking at their website, it looks like you can do http://www.flipkart.com/search/a/all?query=something and it appears to work for ISBN barcodes as well (try to replace `something` with `0671737635` in that query).

Comment: Thank you very much eternalmatt

Comment: How did u find out the url?I would also like to know the  for ebay.com and junglee.com.Thank you for your help.

Comment: I just went to the website, typed "something" into the search bar, looked at the URL, and deleted all the information after `?query=something` key value pair.  But like Romin said, this is a "flaky solution and not recommended."

Comment: Will you please tell me(the url for search through barcode) for ebay and junglee.com as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach in today's times is to use a public API that is exposed by Flipkart. Given that Flipkart has not done that, there is not going to be an easy way to get access to that information.

Web Crawlers exist, but in almost all cases, you will end up violating the terms and conditions and/or any acceptable rate limits. Even though you may come up with a web crawler solution, chances are that it will break sooner or later, if there are internal page changes, which will make you again write new logic. In summary, these are flaky solutions and not recommended, though in the short term, it might look like it works.

Whether it is Flipkart or anyone else, as mentioned above, a public API is the correct integration mechanism. The API would clearly define:

1. What the functionality is i.e. API methods
2. The Data Formats for REquest/REsponse
3. Acceptable Rate Limits for Free usage
4. Paid API charges for higher quota limits

P.S: Flipkart most likely would even have a private API that they use but just that it is not exposed to the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

For Junglee I tried and what I found is the way you can search items using a URL, [http://www.junglee.com/mn/search/junglee/ref=nav_sb_noss?url=node%3D792284031&field-keywords=](http://www.junglee.com/mn/search/junglee/ref=nav_sb_noss?url=node=792284031&field-keywords=)

so, if your search product is iphone (not the best example for android developers) pass it as a string to this URL
http://www.junglee.com/mn/search/junglee/ref=nav_sb_noss?url=node%3D792284031&field-keywords=iphone